# Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: Recipient email address is not set or empty

Tags: php, html, email, forgot-password

I need some help i am trying to create a form that will allow users to get otp to their email address, but the problem now i am getting this problem "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: Recipient email address is not set or empty". I dont want to create an email to myself, as it will prevent users not to receive an email to their account. Rather i want them when submitting the form, whatever their email account used should allow them to receive their otp account to their email with a link redirect them to use otp verification.

````
<?php
```
`session_start();

// Get the directory of the current script
$currentDir = __DIR__;

$phpMailerDir = 'C:\wamp64\www\obaju\distribution\sendEmails\vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer';

require_once $phpMailerDir . '\src\PHPMailer.php';
require_once $phpMailerDir . '\src\SMTP.php';
require_once $phpMailerDir . '\src\Exception.php';

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

// Create a new PHPMailer instance
/* Create a new PHPMailer object. Passing TRUE to the constructor enables exceptions. */
$mail = new PHPMailer(TRUE);

try {
    // Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_OFF;
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'smtp-mail.outlook.com'; // Enter your SMTP server here
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = "gcira2023@outlook.com";
    $mail->Password = "***"; // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->Port = 587; // Port number depends on your SMTP server configuration

    // Sender and recipient details
    if(isset($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['email'])){
        $recipient_email = $_POST['email'];
        $mail->addAddress($recipient_email, 'Recipient Name');
    } else {
        throw new Exception('Recipient email address is not set or empty.');
    }

    // Email content
    $mail->isHTML(false);
    $mail->Subject = 'Password Reset';
    $otp = rand(100000, 999999);
    $_SESSION['otp'] = $otp; // Store the OTP in a session variable
    $mail->Body = 'Your OTP code is: ' . $otp;

    // Send the email
    if (!$mail->send()) {
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        // Redirect the user to the OTP verification page
        //header('Location: otp-confirmation.php');
        //exit;
    }

} catch (Exception $e) {
    // Output an error message if the email failed to send
    echo 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ', $e->getMessage();
}
?>





<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- CSS -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Obaju : e-commerce template</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="robots" content="all,follow">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Font Awesome CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- Google fonts - Roboto -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,700">
    <!-- owl carousel-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/owl.carousel/assets/owl.carousel.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/owl.carousel/assets/owl.theme.default.css">
<!-- JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.3/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- owl carousel-->
    
  </head>
  <body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="card mt-5">
        <div class="card-header">
          Reset Password
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <form id="forgot-password" method="post" action="otp-confirmation.php">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="email">Email</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="new-password">New Password</label>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="new-password" name="new-password" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="confirm-password">Confirm Password</label>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="confirm-password" name="confirm-password" required>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Reset Password</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    <!-- JavaScript files-->
    <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/jquery.cookie/jquery.cookie.js"> </script>
    <script src="vendor/owl.carousel/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/owl.carousel2.thumbs/owl.carousel2.thumbs.js"></script>
    <script src="js/front.js"></script>
    <script src="js/deletion_shopping_cart.js"></script>
    <script src="js/add_to_cart.js"></script>
    <script src="js/forgot-password.js"></script>
</body>
</html>`
```
````

// jquery validation
/*
*@author:Gcobani Mkontwana
*@date:20/04/2023
*Reset password for users.
**/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#forgot-password").submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var formData = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: "forgot-password.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: formData,
            success: function(data){
                if(data == "success"){
                    alert("Password reset successfully.");
                    window.location.href = "dashboard.php";
                }
                
            }
            
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: If you first load the script , there is no POST data and hence the else block will be executed , throwing the exception "Recipient email address is not set or empty." . Try clicking the reset password button (after entering a valid email address in the input box) and see what happens

Comment: @KenLee nothing happens, let me share my jquery forgot-password, but the form has action="POST"